# java code not compiling without any error

Tags: java

This code is not working. What could be wrong?
I'm new and I am not able to understand what is wrong. I'm compiling using an app. The code runs but there is no printout there. What should I do.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*we will make a game in which we try to get same number on all of our dice. And count how much tries it take to match the dice.
        */

        int a = keepRolling();
        System.out.println(a);

    }

    //creating dice function first
    public static int rollDice() {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
        int randomAccurate = (int) randomNumber;
        randomAccurate = randomAccurate + 1;
        return randomAccurate;

    }


    public static int keepRolling() {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        int count = 1; //one time is already rolled when the function is called
        while (!(roll1 == roll2)) {
            int roll1 = rollDice();
            int roll2 = rollDice();
            count = count + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: define "not working". That code will show an output in your console (at least if you compiled it after your last changes), unless your keepRolling goes into an endless loop, if both rolls are never equal

Comment: and actually could you tell us what have you done to debug it?

Comment: can't say if its your "app" problem? you could also try running in any standard online compilers.

Comment: Not working even if we multiply it by 2 instead of 6. Online compilers not working.

Answer (score 2):

It might take a long time to print it (you created a kind of infinite loop). The chances of condition

```
 while (!(roll1 == roll2)) is very rare to be false.
```

Because both roll1 and roll2 have random numbers and being them equal is rare and time consuming. This is why your program will keep on running (or might give stackoverflow exception) and in very rare occassions might print the count.

Unrelated : you should have used

```
while(roll1 != roll2) instead of while (!(roll1 == roll2))
```

and not create new variable under the loop (use previous variables declared at method start)

Comment: they are cast to int and to roll two equal dice happens quite often...

Comment: he has created new variables under while block scope

Comment: ok, you mean without correction of the code, then it will run forever or print 1, chances 5 : 1

Answer (score 1):

You are usign new variables in the loop, roll1 and roll2 never change, it should be

```
public static int keepRolling() {
    int roll1 = rollDice();
    int roll2 = rollDice();
    int count = 1; //one time is already rolled when the function is called
    while (!(roll1 == roll2)) {
        roll1 = rollDice();
        roll2 = rollDice();
        count = count + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rollDice,take care this method.
it's build with Math.random()
you never know what number it's,which means if you wanna see print something,it could be forever.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

```
    public static int keepRolling() {
        int dice1, dice2, count = 0; 
        do {
            dice1 = rollDice();
            dice2 = rollDice();
            count++;
        } while (dice1 != dice2);
        return count;
    }
```

roll1 and roll2 is completely removed in this case

Comment: no, you can't. this won't compile since you try to compare dice1 and dice2 before (and in a scope they don't) they exist. move the declarations and initial assigning of value outside of the while